# How to send an AWS SNS mail, and what are the prerequisites for it's implementation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue, amazon-sns

I have a glue job which runs from a python script. I want to implement a way such that if any job run fails then a sns mail trigger to the recipents about the job failure along with it should have the output logs screenshot for the **last failed job** which can be accessed in the cloudwatch. If this is possible, can anyone provide a step by step procedure to implement this in aws and what are prequisites or services that needs to be enabled to acheive this implementation.

I have checked some ways like creating an SNS topic and then creating a cloudwatch events rule but, in this case the email contains only the status of job i.e. "failed", "success" .etc. Referred this page on [Medium.com](https://medium.com/srcecde/send-notification-based-on-cloudwatch-logs-filter-patterns-41bcf616cd02)

Comment: In general a Lambda would be able to do this.  It would be SNS -> Lambda -> SES and Cloudwatch.  But this is a very broad question and not trivial.

Comment: It is really difficult to get the logs included in an alert like that. That question has been asked many times on here. You basically have to trigger a Lambda function which then queries the CloudWatch Logs API to go find the logs (which itself can be difficult to determine exactly which lines in the logs should be included with the event) and then have Lambda piece together an email from that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.